# Surjective function for the intersection of two sets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I have two sets $A$ and $B$ that are both countable sets. There exists surjective functions such that $g: \mathbb{Z}^+ \rightarrow A$ and $h: \mathbb{Z}^+ \rightarrow B$. If I take the intersection $A \cap B$ and want to make a surjective function for it, what would that look like?

I think that it is $f: \mathbb{Z}^+ \rightarrow (A \cap B)$ but I am not entirely sure.

If this is the correct way of writing this function, how would I go about proving this?

Comment: The statement you are trying to prove is not true without additional hypotheses.

Comment: Are you trying to show that $A\cap B$ is also countable, and to do so by showing that there is a surjection from the positive integers onto $A\cap B$, and you want to try to construct it from $g$ and $h$, is that it? Note that you could have $A\cap B$ emtpy, in which case you have no functions from $\mathbb{Z}^+$ to $A\cap B$, let alone surjective ones...